# Specific SSH access via IP address range, NOT via subnet

Tags: 16.04

I'm looking to allow SSH access via an IP address range that does not fit neatly into a subnet. Just as an example, 192.168.10.60 thru 192.168.10.80.

I only want a group of so many IPs allowed to SSH to an Ubuntu 16.04 box. This obviously does fit neatly in a subnet, so using 192.168.10.0/24 for 192.168.10.* will allow IPs outside the 60-80 group.

Other than listing each IP address individually, how can a group be allowed? I tried using 192.168.10.60-80 and that did not work. I tried it in /etc/hosts/allow and in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 192.168.10.60-80 you "might" try 192.168.10.60-192.168.10.80, but from what I've been reading, unfortunately I think you are going to have to list each ip. "*@192.168.10.60 *@192.168.10.61 *@192.168.10.62 *@192.168.10.63" etc.  It could be worse, that's "only" 20 entries, with copy paste it should old take a couple minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Tried different combinations of that, with spaces before and/or after the dash, full IP or just the last subnet like in my original post. That did not work.

I had to list them all individually to make it work.